# Django, handling multiple forms. Forms referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have two forms in my view: `BookingForm` and `ReviewForm`. I want to submit and process these forms independently in my `template.html`. I added the '`booking'` and `'review'` in the name tag of my forms in `template.html`

For the booking form, I simply want to redirect, but for the ReviewForm I would like to create a record in my DB.

Here's my **views.py**

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if 'booking' in request.POST:
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #process the form
            return redirect()
    elif 'review' in request.POST:
        review_form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if review_form.is_valid():
            review_form.save()
            return redirect()
else:
    form = BookingForm()
    review_form = ReviewForm()
return render(request, "template.html", context={"form": form,"review_form":review_form})
```

However, for some reason, I get the error that `form` and `review_form` are referenced before assignment.

---

Another thing, since Review Model has to be associated with another Model (call it Item). I would like to automatically get the item data and associate my review with the item when I call `review_form.save()`.
I'm thinking something along the lines of `review_form['item']=kwargs['pk']` (Not sure if this will work). I'm using a DetailView structure and the page has  parameter from urls.py, associated with the item, stored as `item_id=kwargs['pk']` in my view.

```
class Review(models.Model):
    #other fields
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)

class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('title','star','photo','name','email','body')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, adding a `name` attribute to a form does nothing. That value still won't be sent to the view. So, neither of your conditions are true on POST, and both form and booking_form are undefined.

The way to do this is to add the attribute to the *submit* button.

However, this will still leave a problem, in that if the POST contains one of these values but that form is not valid, the other form remains undefined. You should ensure that both are defined no matter what is in the post data.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I did add the name tags to submit buttons. Do I need 2 separate if 'booking' in and if 'review' in statements, or is it possible to have 1 loop. Also, could you suggest how to  handle .save() I talked about for next part. Will my idea work?

Comment: I just seems that the code has way too many if and else statements which is hard to read